# Chrome 69 doesn't accept cookie on 127.0.0.1 anymore

Tags: google-chrome, web, cookies

Chrome 69 behaviour seams to have been changed concerning cookies on 127.0.0.1. It was a known issue that you can not set cookies on localhost because that is not a valid domain name. But a workaround was to define your own domain in /etc/hosts (e.g. example.com -> 127.0.0.1). Then you can set cookies on example.com. But this doesn't work anymore in Chrome 69. It does work when you point the domain to the external IP address of the machine, but that is assigned by DHCP and changes. Anyone know why this is the new behaviour and what a better workaround would be?

Answer (score 1):

Ok to answer my own question: apparently cookies aren't accepted anymore if you override an existing domain name in /etc/hosts. E.g. if you have the following entry in `/etc/hosts` :

`google.com 127.0.0.1`

then your local webserver can not set a cookie in it's response anymore. So always pick a non-existing domain for testing purposes:

`notreallygoogle.com 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

You can add into /etc/hosts "https://localdomain" or "http://localdomain".

Try it.