# Cookie is set in Response Header but not in browser

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

I am working on a hybrid angular application using angularja and angular 8. I am trying to implement a cookie that needs to get set after login using POST request but the problem is that after login, the cookie POST request is getting successfully called and the cookie is visible in the response header in the network tab but not in response header and also on navigating to cookies in application tab, a cookie is not getting stored. I have tried all the possible solutions but to no avail. Any possible solution

**Logic for cookie implementation after successful login**

```
                  fetch(glAccountsUrl+`/api/oauth/v3/cookie`, {
                    'method': 'POST',
                    'credentials': 'include',                    
                    'headers': { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jwt.token'))}`,'Content-Type': 'application/json','Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true },
                    'body': JSON.stringify(cookieObj)
                  })
                      .then((response) => {
                          return response.json();
                      })
                      .then((data)=>{
                        console.log(data.message);
                      })
                }
```

**screenshots**

[image: cookies in response header]

[image: no cookie in response header]

[image: cookie not stored]

Comment: Your first screenshot shows a ⚠️ next to the Set-Cookie header, so I think the issue is with the cookie itself, and not your fetch code. Does hovering that icon show any more information?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72939811/fetch-not-setting-cookie-despite-set-cookie-header there was a similar issue here, it might also some provide some clues as to why it is not getting set. Your backend might be different though but the principles are likely the same.

Comment: @CBroe actually at that time i was using local environment but i have deployed the code to staging environment and in that environment it is not showing any warning or issue symbol so problem might be something else

Comment: In your Set-Cookie header from the screenshot, it has `Max-Age={formatted date}` at the end, that would definitively be wrong - this value needs to be a _number_, the number of seconds until this cookie is supposed to expire.

Comment: Here is your answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183751/chrome-69-doesnt-accept-cookie-on-127-0-0-1-anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183751/chrome-69-doesnt-accept-cookie-on-127-0-0-1-anymore)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Set-Cookie is being filtered out on fetch calls, as per the spec here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

> Warning: Browsers block frontend JavaScript code from accessing the Set-Cookie header, as required by the Fetch spec, which defines Set-Cookie as a forbidden response-header name that must be filtered out from any response exposed to frontend code.

I don't have any recommendations on alternatives that you can use though, I THINK this behaviour is different if you use something that wraps XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: That is only about trying to access the `Set-Cookie` response header _via code_ - it has nothing to do with what cookies `fetch` itself will send or receive. (JavaScript access _must_ be disallowed, because the cookie might not be for the domain the code is running under.)

Comment: You are right, I missed that, thanks.

Comment: @CBRoe i tried using XMLHttpRequest for post api call and even after using that also the cookie is not getting set on the browser